# Modify javascript map result

Tags: javascript, node.js

i created code for getting info from api list,

all worked well, then i tried to `.splite` (Just modify) one of the object

```
var USERNAME = JSON.parse(body).map(z=>z.name);



      var LIST =  USERNAME.map(function(a,b){
                        var DISCORD = JSON.parse(body).map(e=> e.identifiers.filter(c => c.startsWith("discord:")))


                let s = b + 1;


                return[s + '. ' + a + " " + DISCORD[b].split(':')[1]];
            })
            var LIST = LIST.join("\n");

 }
```

**DISCORD returns discord:id (id - number)** and i just want the **ID**

Error code: `DISCORD[b].split is not a function`

Comment: `DISCORD` is an array of arrays (`[[..], [..], [..]]`), arrays don't have a `.split` function.

Comment: So you have any idea to modify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DISCORD` is an array of arrays (`[[..], [..], [..]]`), arrays don't have a `.split` function. I think you want to do something like this:

```
const list = JSON.parse(body).map((o, i) => {
  let identifier = o.identifiers.find(v => v.startsWith("discord:"))
  if (identifier) {
    identifier = identifier.split(':')[1];
  } else {
    identifier = '';
  }
  const nr = i + 1;
  return `${nr}. ${o.name} ${identifier}`;
});
```

I've based this on the assumption that `body` is a JSON formatted string that looks something like this:

```
[{
  "name": string,
  "identifiers": [string, ...., 'discord:something', ....]
}, 
.....
]
```